# try to build Recursive data structures on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tree, height

Hey guys I have a mission on my course that I need to build a function that given a tree (tree) is represented as a tuple returns a new tree (show of Tree)

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, value, nodes=None):
        self.value = value
        self.nodes = nodes

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.nodes:
            return 'Tree({0},{1})'.format(self.value, repr(self.nodes))
        return 'Tree({0})'.format(self.value)


def BuildTree(tree):
    if type(tree) != tuple:
        return Tree(tree)
    <3 >
    return Tree("here i need to put the height" ,list(map(BuildTree, tree)))


t1 = BuildTree((((1, 2), 3), (4, (5, 6))))
print(t1)
```

and until now I get only like this.

> Tree([Tree([Tree([Tree(1), Tree(2)]), Tree(3)]), Tree([Tree(4), Tree([Tree(5), Tree(6)])])])

But I don't know I calculate the height of each internal node

[image]
I have this pic that describes the construction of the new tree.
So the numbers in green are the height and the numbers in red are values I have inside the tuple

so the correct output of the new Tree is like that.

> Tree(3,[Tree(2,[Tree(1,[Tree(1), Tree(2)]), Tree(3)]), Tree(2,[Tree(4), Tree(1,[Tree(5), Tree(6)])])])

Answer (score 0):

Let's describe `height` in plain words -

1. the height of the empty tree is `0`
2. the height of the non-empty tree is `1` plus the max height of the children nodes

We can write this using mathematical induction

1. if the input tree, `t` is empty, return the empty result
2. (induction) `t` is not empty. add 1 to the `max` of solved sub-problems, `t.nodes`, and return

```py
def height (t):
  if not t:
    return 0                                    # (1)
  else:
    return 1 + max(height(n) for n in t.nodes)  # (2)
```

For this to work however, you need to initialize `nodes=[]` instead of `nodes=None`. Otherwise it complicates your program a bit more -

1. if the input tree, `t` is empty, return the empty result
2. (induction) `t` is not empty. if `t.nodes` is empty, a leaf node has been reached; return 1
3. (induction) `t` is not empty and `t.nodes` is not empty. add 1 to the `max` of solved sub-problems, `t.nodes`, and return

```py
def height (t):
  if not t:
    return 0                                   # (1)
  elif not t.nodes:
    return 1                                   # (2)
  else:
    return 1 + max(height(n) for n in t.nodes) # (3)
```

Comment: but i need to do this in one line(pipline) without call any function.
you can use "lambda , map, filter, max, sum" you can use what you want but no to create function...

Comment: nodes need to stay none... if you can create one line like the height function it will be great

Answer (score 0):

```
h = lambda x: 1 + max(list(map(h, x))) if type(x) == tuple else 0
```

Comment: While this may be an answer to OP's problem, code-only answers are [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on StackOverflow. Please consider adding some explanation to the code provided as it will benefit both OP and future visitors